# Is there a way to get country code with pgeocode?

Tags: python, geolocation, zipcode, country-codes

I have seen in the documentation of `pgeocde` (https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/) that you first have to pass in the `country code` in order to get country information. However, I cannot find anything on getting the country information by passing parameters such as `country name` or country `zip code`. I am wondering if this is possible?

From documentation:

```
>>> import pgeocode

>>> nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('fr')
>>> nomi.query_postal_code("75013")
postal_code               75013
country code                 FR
place_name             Paris 13
state_name        Île-de-France
state_code                   11
county_name               Paris
county_code                  75
community_name            Paris
community_code              751
latitude                48.8322
longitude                2.3561
accuracy                      5
```

So, instead of passing `fr` (which is a `country code`) as a parameter, is there a way to pass in the `country name` or `zip code` in order to get country information?

Answer (score 2):

This library does not appear to have any functionality to begin with a zip code and derive the country. However, you could write a function to do this by by looping all the supported countries and seeing which ones have a `postal_code` that matches the one you have started with. To loop all possible countries, you reference `pgeocode.COUNTRIES_VALID` and do something like making a dictionary of each response:

```
import pgeocode
dfs = {}
for i in pgeocode.COUNTRIES_VALID:
   nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim(i)
   # this code will always return a dataframe
   # if the postal_code has no match, the df values will all be NaN 
   df = nomi.query_postal_code("75013")
   dfs[i] = df
```

Note that this approach will not be memory efficient. If you look at the source code for pgeocode (https://github.com/symerio/pgeocode/blob/master/pgeocode.py), you'll see that you could probably gain a lot of efficiency by indexing the underlying data and querying that index.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I will give this a try!